# T-SQL Replacement for Access Normalization Using Record Set?

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, merge, database-normalization, recordset

I'm relatively new to T-SQL, so I hope someone with more experience/knowledge can help.

I have inherited an Access database that I'm moving to SQL Server. The original database imports and normalizes transaction data from Excel files in the following steps:

1. imports the Excel file to a staging table,
2. updates tables related to several of the columns if any new values are found, and
3. finally moves the data to the main table, but with inner joins to the PK columns on the updated tables from step 2 replacing the actual values.

Step 2 above makes use of a "normalizing" table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblNormalize](
    [Normalize_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Table_Raw] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Field_Raw] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Table_Normal] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Field_Normal] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Data_Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [tblNormalize$ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Normalize_ID] ASC
        )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

- [Table_Raw] is the name of the staging table.
- [Field_Raw] is the name of the field in the staging table - necessary since the field name could be different from what's in the tables to be updated.
- [Table_Normal] is the name of the table to be updated.
- [Field_Normal] is the name of the field to be updated.

For example, if one of the values in the Location column of the staging table is "Tennessee", this step would check the corresponding Location column in the Location table to make sure that "Tennessee" exists, and if not, inserts it as a new record and creates a new primary key.

So my question: How do I accomplish this step in T-SQL, without using a record set in Access? I've figured out how to use MERGE in a stored procedure to do it for individual columns with the relevant tables, but still using a record set in VBA to move through each row of the normalizing table while calling the stored procedure. (All the tables now reside on on SQL Server, and I've linked to them in Access using ODBC.) Here's what I have so far:

VBA:

```vb
Public Function funTestNormalize(strTableRaw As String)
'---Normalizes the data in the tblPayrollStaging table after it's been imported, using the dbo_tblNormalize table---
    Dim db As Database, rst As Recordset, qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From dbo_tblNormalize WHERE Table_Raw = '" & strTableRaw & "';", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    'Cycle through each row of dbo_tblNormalize (corresponds to the fields in tblPayrollStaging)
    If Not rst.EOF Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassThru") 'Sets the QueryDef
            qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblSheet").Connect 'Assigns a connection to the QueryDef
            qdef.ReturnsRecords = False 'Avoids the "3065 error"
        Do Until rst.EOF
            With qdef
                .SQL = "EXEC uspUpdateNormalizingTables " & rst![Table_Raw] & ", " & rst![Field_Raw] & ", " & rst![Table_Normal] & ", " & rst!Field_Normal & ";" 'Sets the .SQL value to the needed T-SQL
                .Execute dbFailOnError 'Executes the QueryDef
            End With
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rst.Close
End Function
```

SQL Server (using SSMS):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateNormalizingTables]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tableRaw nvarchar(50),
    @fieldRaw nvarchar(50),
    @tableNormal nvarchar(50),
    @fieldNormal nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @tableNormal + ' (' + @fieldNormal + ')' +
    ' SELECT DISTINCT ' + @tableRaw + '.' + @fieldRaw +
    ' FROM ' + @tableRaw +
    ' WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT ' + @fieldNormal + ' FROM ' + @tableNormal + ' WHERE ' + @tableNormal + '.' + @fieldNormal + ' = ' + @tableRaw + '.' + @fieldRaw + ')) AND (' + @tableRaw + '.' + @fieldRaw + ' IS NOT NULL);')
END
GO
```

Would I need to use cursors (which I haven't used yet, and would have to figure out), or is there maybe a more elegant solution which I haven't considered? Any help you can give is appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: This seems to deal with data [tag:normalization] in a database but not [tag:database-normalization]. The latter is about eliminating base table columns with undesired structure or replacing a base table by others that join to it. Also it would help a lot if you were more clear/concrete re both what you are doing now & what the result is as a function of input & the T-SQL parts you are proposing. See [mcve].

Comment: Are you looking to parse a table row by row using T-SQL? Since that can be done relatively easily using a `CURSOR`. Since I don't know exactly what you're checking, this question is a bit unclear. You could add sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Please do not clarify in comments, edit your post to incorporate them in the best presentation possible. Please reread & act on the comments above re text for tables etc & [mcve]. Eg that table should be text. An executable text version should also be somewhere as part of a MCVE.